# Disabled nginx service, But the IP is still accessible

Tags: systemd, ip, services, nginx, webserver

I have disabled nginx.service and have restarted my Ubuntu 18.04.

```bsh
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep ngin
nginx.service                  disabled 

$ systemctl is-active nginx.service
inactive
```

But when I do

```bsh
$ hostname -I
192.168.0.102 192.168.0.101 172.17.0.1
```

And I get the Nginx welcome page when I browse to `172.17.0.1`.

> ## Welcome to nginx!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
>   working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to
>   [nginx.org](http://nginx.org/).
>   Commercial support is available at
>   [nginx.com](http://nginx.com/).
>
> *Thank you for using nginx.*

- I don't understand, how the IP is still accessible given that the service is disabled?
- How can I make sure that the nginx is not running?
- How can I prevent nginx from automatically starting on reboot?

I am facing Ram shortage and I want to disable all unnecessary services.

Comment: Stop the service `systemctl stop nginx.service`

Comment: But this does not persist after reboot.

Comment: CHeck with netstat what exactly listen on this port

Comment: `netstat | grep 172.17.0.1` returns nothing.

Comment: Try `netstat -an|grep LISTEN|grep 80`

Comment: Nothing related to nginx. 
`unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     40166    /run/docker/libnetwork/51f7bca0f1c228cf737665980708fd77f4905269b7c7e72325237be80a053c3c.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1185080  /tmp/vscode-768f57cefe9c96673ef72113c61374fad2d4f853.sock`

Comment: do you have a socket service that activates nginx?  https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/237

Comment: @JeffSchaller Doesn't `systemctl list-unit-files` lists all types of unit files, including sockets? I was aware that it did. Am I wrong?

Comment: maybe it's not named with `ngin`??

Answer (score 1):

Probably someone just runs it from shell, not via systemd.

```
    # systemctl status nginx
    ● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: inactive (dead) 
    # systemctl status `ps h -C nginx -o pid`
    session-1.scope - Session 1 of user username
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/transient/session-1.scope; transient)
Transient: yes
   Active: active (abandoned) since Thu 2019-02-07 15:59:14 CET; 2 weeks 4 days ago
    Tasks: 20
   Memory: 1.3G
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-1.scope
           ├─ 1156 journalctl -fl -p 6
           ├─ 2101 SCREEN
           ├─ 2102 /bin/bash
           ├─ 2158 sudo -i
           ├─ 2160 -bash
           ├─ 2205 /bin/bash
           ├─ 8615 /bin/bash
           ├─ 8671 mutt
           ├─ 8676 /bin/bash
           ├─20240 sudo -i
           ├─20242 -bash
           ├─23962 systemctl status 30810 30827 30828 30829 30830
           ├─23963 less
           ├─30810 nginx: master process nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
           ├─30827 nginx: worker process
           ├─30828 nginx: worker process
           ├─30829 nginx: worker process
           └─30830 nginx: worker process
```

The solution is `killall nginx` as root. Or `systemd stop session-1.scope` (replace session-1.scope with your one ), but it will kill all the process for that user session.

Comment: Hi, How can I prevent nginx from automatically starting on reboot? The thing is that I am facing Ram shortage and I want to disable all unnecessary services.

Comment: Show the output of `systemctl status $(ps h -C nginx -o pid)`. It will help to answer a lot of questions.

Comment: [Gist: systemctl status $(ps h -C nginx -o pid)](https://gist.github.com/Agarwal-Nikhil/e5879e252577fa9b17f25c8faf0d0437)

Output of `ps h -C nginx -o pid` is blank